# Magento: Product List Override

Tags: php, magento

Thanks for taking a look at this. I’ve been looking and looking for a solution to what seems like a simple thing to do but nothing yet. Here goes:

When you click on "Specialty" in the main menu it goes here:

```
Home /Specialty
```

When you click one of the product images on the home page it goes here:

```
Home /Specialty /Holiday Satin Stocking (Full product description page)
```

I need all products with full product information to end up at

```
Home /Specialty
```

Page set-up would be: Click on Menu item or an image to show like this:

```
|||Product1|||   Product Description   Add to cart

|||Product2|||   Product Description   Add to cart

|||Product3|||   Product Description   Add to cart
```

I would like to override going "Home /Specialty /Holiday Satin Stocking" all together with listing all the information here: Home /Specialty

"Specialty" is set up as an anchor and all products types are simple.

[image: Here's a sample of what I'm trying to do]

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit the product list template and add in the appropriate getters ($_product->getDescription, etc.) to that phtml file.

Comment: Thanks so much for responding. Your answer makes total sense...just alot of code to go through. The "list.phtml" will be the only place I have to change anything?